# Access denied by business data connectivity error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I created external content type in the sharepoint designer and created a list. I went to the URL and when refresh the page the list appeared. When I click the list it is showing as

> "Access denied by Business Data Connectivity. Correlation
>   ID:bab07ba2-5ac1-463c-ab8d-f4f2233fb26"

In Central admin i gave the permissions for my account to that external content type. 
Still it is showing this message. What is the solution for this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the solution. Need to add the

> "Set metadata store permission"

[image]

I added my user here. The list now generated with out any problem.

Thank you all.

Comment: Took me a while to figure out where your screen is located, so if anyone is looking for that: Central Administration - Application Management - Service Applications - Manage service applications - Business Data Connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Go to: Central Admin -> Manage Service Application (http://CentralAdminURL/_admin/ServiceApplications.aspx) -> Business Data Connectivity Service

Then select the External Content type you are looking for and make sure you provide permissions (buttons at the ribbon) to all authenticated users.

Regards
Ronald